# How can I get the X axis labels in Flot to be transformed with my data?

Tags: jquery, flot

I am using [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) to chart some data that I pull back from the server.  The X-axis data that I receive is in units of milliseconds, and I want to display the chart with the X-axis in units of seconds.  So, I thought this was a good use of the [API](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/API.txt)'s `transform` axis option.  I applied my transform like so:

```
var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"),
       { 
         grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true },
         xaxis: { transform: function(x) { return x/1000; } }
       });
```

I can see that my transform function is being called by the framework, and I can see that the points themselves are being transformed -- when I bind the `plothover` event and hover over the points, I can see that the X value is suitably transformed.  The problem is that the x-axis tick labels are not also getting transformed.

What do I need to do to get the axis labels themselves transformed with my data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what the "right" answer is, but you can provide your own tick labelling function, and just have it perform the same job as your transform function.

```
var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"),
   { 
     grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true },
     xaxis: { transform: function(x) { return x/1000; },
              tickFormatter: function(x) { return x/1000; } }
   });
```