# Flot With "String" x-axis

Tags: flot

When using flot I would like to have a string based x-axis. For example I have a list of customers "Bob", "Chris", "Joe" and would like to plot their revenue on the Y-Axis. (this is a bar graph)

It seems at first glance flot only supports numeric types on the x-axis. Is this true?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

[@Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5821134/662581) is close, but it would make more sense to just use the `ticks` option to directly specify what ticks should have what labels:

```
var options = {

...
  xaxis: {
    ticks: [[0,'Bob'],[1,'Chris'],[2,'Joe']]
  }
...

};
```

**EDIT**: it looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/nULPV/994/) (I added more data than labels, but you get the idea).

Comment: There's also a "categories" plugin : http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/categories/ – but I haven't been able to have proper labels on the x axis for now :/

Comment: @Aheho - thanks, I updated it to point to a source of flot that actually exists :)

Comment: @OlivierLance Thanks! for the link

Answer (score 18):

You should be able to do this using the `tickFormatter` option as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768348/). I haven't tried it myself, but give this a shot:

```
var xAxisLabels = ['Bob', 'Chris', 'Joe'];    
function xAxisLabelGenerator(x){
    return xAxisLabels[x];
}

var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), { 
    // snip other options...
    xaxis: {
       transform: xAxisLabelGenerator,
       tickFormatter: xAxisLabelGenerator 
    }
});
```

This means that the actual x-values should be `0, 1, 2, ...`

Comment: +1 - It may not have been the chosen answer (which I also upvoted) but this is very useful.

Comment: the x parameter on your label generator, where does that come from?

Comment: @KasperSkov flot passes the parameter to the callback you specify.

Comment: Really? That makes no sense to me :) I would think you would have to do something like 

transform:function (x) {
        return xAxisLabelGenerator(x);
      }

Comment: @KasperSkov `transform:function (x) { return xAxisLabelGenerator(x); }` is an unnecessarily verbose, though equivalent, way of writing what's in my answer: `transform: xAxisLabelGenerator`.

Answer (score 18):

The Categories plugin (jquery.flot.categories.js) will do this quite nicely, so that data can be formatted like this:

```
var data = [ ["January", 10], ["February", 8], ["March", 4], ["April", 13], ["May", 17], ["June", 9] ];
```

and plot like this:
[image]

See: http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/categories/index.html

Comment: Worked like a charm!