# FLOT Charts: Customising Axis

Tags: math, charts, flot

I need to figure out how to do two custom axises with flot charts.

For the Y-Axis it must only show rounded numbers such as 100, 200, 400, 1000, 2000, 4000, 6000
So the first digit can be either a 1, or a multiple of 2. It can be 300, 500, 700 etc

the X-Axis must be broken down to exactly Week1, Week2, Week3, Week4, and Week5 for a month.
(It's fixed that even if there isnt enough days to fill it doesn't need to stretch to the end.
It's to show the break down of one month.)

Comment: Figured out the first part: http://jsbin.com/wawetoto/1/
<pre>
   var num = [1, 2, 5, 6, 10, 20, 30];
   function evenSteven(element){
     firstDigit = parseInt(element.toString().substring(0,1), 10);
  
     if (firstDigit % 2 === 0 || firstDigit === 1) {
       return element;
     }
    }
var filteredNum = num.filter(evenSteven);
console.log(filteredNum);
</pre>

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820954/flot-with-string-x-axis)